# zf2 doctrine2 editAction

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am facing an error to edit the values of my Entity Category. Here is my code

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('application/default', array('action'=>'edit','id' => $child->getId()));?>">Bearbeiten</a>
```

In my IndexController is the Action:

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $category = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Category')->find($id);

        $form = new CategoryForm();
        $form->setHydrator(new CategoryHydrator());
        $form->bind($category);

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if($request->isPost())
        {

            $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if($form->isValid())
            {   
                $object = $form->getData();
                $category->setName($object->getName());
                $category->setDescription($object->getDescription());
                $category->setParent($object->getParent());
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
            }   
        }

        return array(
                            'form' => $form
                    );  
    }
```

Here is my CategoryForm.php:

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class CategoryForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('categoryForm');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'id' => 'name',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Ihr Name:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'description',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'id' => 'description',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Ihre Beschreibung:',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'parent',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'id' => 'parent',
                        'name' => 'parent',
                        'type' => 'hidden',
                ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name'=>'submit',
            'attributes'=>array(
                        'type' => 'submit',
                        'value' => 'OK',
            ),
        ));

    }
}
```

And the following is my edit.phtml:

```
<?php
 $form = $this->form;

 $form->prepare();

 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('description'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('parent'));
 echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
```

By calling the action 'edit', the browser shows a error with the message:

```
Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion
```

Does someone knows my mistake and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

First, from your question it can only be quessed what the $child->getId() is. I assume the $child is an instance of the Category class, and getId() returns an integer, being the category's id. So instead, i just put this, for testing, in my index.phtml:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('application/default', array('action'=>'edit','id' => 1));?>">Bearbeiten</a>
```

To be on the safe side, I have also passed an instance of Category to index.phtml as $child variable, used your code for the link, and the link worked, (so it's not something wrong with url view helper). Anyway, I could just write the url into the browser and click enter, but since I don't know where your error showed up, (perhaps after clicking the link), I had to make sure :)

Next, I copied your code exactly, except for this line:

```
$form->setHydrator(new CategoryHydrator());
```

You did not provide the code for your hydrator. I assume you've created it, but without it being shown to me, I can only assume there is an error somewhere in the hydrator code. Instead of that line, try:

```
$form->setHydrator ( new \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject ( $em, 'Application\Entity\Category' ) );
```

I hope I can safely assume that DoctrineModule was installed with composer and is added to your 'modules' array in application.config.php.

With this line, otherwise the code being exactly as yours, after a click on the link, or entering the URI /application/edit/1 ( 1 being the id of my category to edit), the form was displayed and the input fields were populated correctly, without any errors.

If there's still something wrong, perhaps there is some error in your Category entity.